# Accessing jax-rs (CXF) MessageContext outside service class in Spring (2.5)

Tags: spring, aop, cxf

I'm trying to access the MessageContext (or WebServiceContext) in an aspect to get access to the HTTPServletRequest for logging purposes. I would like to inject the context like I did for spring-ws but I have not found a way to do it. Here is what I used for spring-ws:

```
<beans:bean id="transportContext" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.context.TransportContextHolder" factory-method="getTransportContext" scope="request">
 <aop:scoped-proxy/>
 </beans:bean>
```

I can't use the @Resource annotation on WebServiceContext field/method  as I am not in the service (tried anyways with no luck). Instantiating the WebServiceContext (ie new WebServiceContextImpl()) doesn't work either, but supposedly should as this just wraps  a threadlocal. I've also tried importing cxf-extension-jaxws.xml and wiring the bean with id org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextImpl with no luck (it's not null but doesn't hold anything) Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spring config (injected as Message or even Map type)

```
    <beans:bean id="currentMessage" class="org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain" factory-method="getCurrentMessage" scope="request">
<aop:scoped-proxy/>
    </beans:bean>
```

then in receiving class

request = (HttpServletRequest)currentMessage.get("HTTP.REQUEST");